# Mapping of nested IEnumerable<IDictionary> to a different type of nested IEnumerable<IDictionary>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, collections

I need to do some "weird" mapping and I've tried a lot of things without getting even close, so I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

I have this "rowDefinition": this is like a contract of how the data in the end should looks like, "1A" and stuff are ID's of data that I'll get from a service

```
var rowDefinitions = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>
        {
            ["Managers"] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["MANAGER_NAME"] = "1A",
                    ["WEBSITE"] = "3A",
                    ["NIP"] = "4A",
                    ["AUM"] = "5A"
                }
            },
            ["Funds"] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["FUND_NAME"] = "6A",
                    ["CURRENCY"] = "2A",
                }
            }
        };
```

And I have this data coming from a service like this, each one of the Dictionaries represents kind of a row for the above structure

```
var dataFromService = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["1A"] = "manager name 1",
                ["3A"] = "website 1",
                ["4A"] = "ni professionals 1",
                ["5A"] = "aum 1"
            },

            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["1A"] = "manager name 2",
                ["3A"] = "website 2",
                ["4A"] = "other ni professional 2",
                ["5A"] = "one more aum 2"
            },
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["6A"] = "fund name 4",
                ["2A"] = "currecy 4",
            },
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["6A"] = "fund name 5",
                ["2A"] = "currecy 5",
            },
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["6A"] = "fund name 6",
                ["2A"] = "currecy 6",
            },
        };
```

I need to map this data according to the "rowDefinition" and get something like this

```
var expectedResult = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>
        {
            ["Managers"] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["MANAGER_NAME"] = "manager name 1",
                    ["WEBSITE"] = "website 1",
                    ["NIP"] = "ni professionals 1",
                    ["AUM"] = "aum 1"
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["MANAGER_NAME"] = "manager name 2",
                    ["WEBSITE"] = "website 2",
                    ["NIP"] = "other ni professional 2",
                    ["AUM"] = "one more aum 2"
                }
            },
            ["Funds"] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["FUND_NAME"] = "fund name 4",
                    ["CURRENCY"] = "currency 4"
                },
                 new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["FUND_NAME"] = "fund name 5",
                    ["CURRENCY"] = "currency 5"
                },
                  new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["FUND_NAME"] = "fund name 6",
                    ["CURRENCY"] = "currency 6"
                }
            }
        };
```

RowDefinitions inside ["Managers"] or ["Funds"] can have more key-value pairs and there can be something else as ["Potato"], in short terms, I should be able to modify rowDefinitions and of course the date I'll get back will include the respective info

This sort of does the job, but looks pretty ugly (and definitely not efficient), I think this can be done with LINQ, but don't know how

```
 private void UglyWay(List<IDictionary<string, object>> dataScopeWithDataPoints, IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>> rowDefinitions)
    {
        var excelData = new Dictionary<string, List<IDictionary<string, object>>>();
        foreach (var dataScope in dataScopeWithDataPoints)
        {
            foreach (var excelRowDefinition in rowDefinitions)
            {
                var rowDefinition = excelRowDefinition.Value.First();
                var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                var found = false;

                foreach (var dataPoint in rowDefinition)
                {
                    if (dataScope.ContainsKey(dataPoint.Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        row[dataPoint.Key] = dataScope[dataPoint.Value.ToString()];
                        found = true;
                    }
                }

                if (found)
                {
                    if (!excelData.ContainsKey(excelRowDefinition.Key))
                    {
                        excelData[excelRowDefinition.Key] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
                    }

                    excelData[excelRowDefinition.Key].Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

If you need any extra information, please just let me know.

Comment: Why does your row definition have a list of dictionaries to define each? Only one entry is possible there, correct? Is that just how the data comes to you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply... in the case of rowDefinition, yes, only one entry is possible.... now for "expectedResult" (same type as rowDefinition) there can be many entries... I could remove this list of dictionaries from rowDefinition, what I cannot chance is "dataFromService" and "expectedResult"

Comment: could I ask you something else?, what if in "rowDefinitions", the ["Manager"] key would also include one field of ["Funds"] like this:
["Managers"] = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["MANAGER_NAME"] = "1A",
                    ["WEBSITE"] = "3A",
                    ["CURRENCY"] = "2A",
                    ["NIP"] = "4A",
                    ["AUM"] = "5A"
                }
            },...

So Currency will be in Funds and Managers at the same time...

Comment: Then the issue would be how to pick which row definition matches a given data dictionary: you could count how many match, or designate a particular field as deciding the match, or make sure all fields match (what if one row definition is a subset of another?).

Comment: I added an example of validating that all field names in the row definition match the data item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the row definition, put in a more usable format, you can extract each matching data dictionary and remap:

```
var ans = rowDefinitions.Select(rd => new { rd.Key, Definition = rd.Value.First().Select(kv => new { kv.Key, Value = kv.Value.ToString() }) })
                        .ToDictionary(rd => rd.Key,
                                      rd => dataFromService.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(rd.Definition.First().Value))
                                                           .Select(d => rd.Definition.ToDictionary(def => def.Key, def => d[def.Value]))
                                                           .ToList()
                        );
```

NOTE: This creates `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>>`. If you really need the `IDictionary` and `IEnumerable`, you can cast the value created from `dataFromService` and convert the `List<>`.

Here is that code:

```
var ans = rowDefinitions.Select(rd => new { rd.Key, Definition = rd.Value.First().Select(kv => new { kv.Key, Value = kv.Value.ToString() }) })
                        .ToDictionary(rd => rd.Key,
                                      rd => dataFromService.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(rd.Definition.First().Value))
                                                           .Select(d => (IDictionary<string,object>)rd.Definition.ToDictionary(def => def.Key, def => d[def.Value]))
                                                           .ToList()
                                                           .AsEnumerable()
                                                           
                        );
```

NOTE: Missing values in `dataFromService` will cause exceptions.

If it is possible for the row definitions to overlap, you can select the row definition that has all matching field names instead of just testing one:

```
var ans2 = rowDefinitions.Select(rd => new { rd.Key, Definition = rd.Value.First().Select(kv => new { kv.Key, Value = kv.Value.ToString() }).ToList() })
                         .ToDictionary(rd => rd.Key,
                                       rd => dataFromService.Where(d => rd.Definition.Count == d.Keys.Count && rd.Definition.All(dkv => d.ContainsKey(dkv.Value)))
                                                            .Select(d => (IDictionary<string,object>)rd.Definition.ToDictionary(def => def.Key, def => d[def.Value]))
                                                            .ToList()
                                                            .AsEnumerable()

                         );
```

Comment: This is just perfect... I don't care about missing values, because they will all be there... thank you very very much!....